# Rock paper scissors game in JavaScript and html with validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a rock, paper scissors game in JavaScript and I am not getting the wins and loses to register right. It keeps selecting option draw. I have spent hours on this and I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

```js
/* Lisa Hergert's javaScript page for the Rock Paper Scissors Game*/

/**
 * getChoice fuction gets the value of userChoice
 * @return - a string
 */

//declare function
function getChoice() {
  var choice = prompt("Do you pick rock, paper or scissors?");
  return choice;
}

/**
 * user displays the userChoice
 * @param - String - the user's choice
 * outputs innerHTML
 */

function userChoice(choice) {
  choice = choice.toUpperCase();
  if (choice != "ROCK" && choice != "PAPER" && choice != "SCISSORS") {
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "You did not enter ROCK, PAPER, or SCISSORS, please try again!";
    choice = prompt("Do you pick rock, paper or scissors?");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = choice;
  }
}

/**
 * computerChoice function generates a random number between 1 and 3 and returns that number
 * @return - a integer
 */

//declare function
function computerChoice() {
  //declare variable randomValue and have it generate a number from 1 to 3
  var randomValue = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 3);
  //declare variable choice
  var compChoice;
  //switch to determine what the number means
  switch (randomValue) {
    case 1:
      compChoice = "ROCK";
      break;
    case 2:
      compChoice = "PAPER";
      break;
    default:
      compChoice = "SCISSORS";
  }
  //return choice
  return compChoice;
}

/**
 * computer displays the computerChoice
 * @param - String - the computer's choice
 * outputs innerHTML
 */

function computer(computer) {
  document.getElementById("computer").innerHTML = computer;
}

/**
 * compare function takes in 1 argument and then using a switch statement returns
 * the result of the game
 * @param - the user's choice of rock, paper or scissors
 * @return - Statement of game result
 */

//declare function and take 1 argument
function compare(choice) {
  //set variable for compChoice and call function
  var compChoice = computerChoice();
  //declare variable 
  var num;
  //set num value based on user choice so that lowercase or capital letters on choices don't matter when comparing
  if (compChoice == "ROCK") {
    num = 1;
  } else if (compChoice == "PAPER") {
    num = 2;
  } else {
    num = 3;
  }
  //switch to determine winner based on choices and them display the result
  switch (choice + num) {
    case "ROCK3":
    case "PAPER1":
    case "SCISSORS2":
      document.write("<p>User wins the game!</p>");
      break;
    case "ROCK2":
    case "PAPER3":
    case "SCISSORS1":
      document.write("<p>User lost the game!</p>");
      break;
    default:
      document.write("<p>This game is a draw, you need to play another game.</p>");
  }
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = choice;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors Game</title>
  <!--Lisa Hergert's Rock Paper Scissors Game-->
  <script src="rockPaperScissors.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rockPaperScissors.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors Game</h1>
  </header>
  <div>
    <p id="user"></p>
    <p id="computer"></p>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <script>
      //Call the functions
      userChoice(getChoice());
      //declare variable compChoice and call the function
      computer(computerChoice());
      //Declare variable result and set it's value by calling the compare function to display the result
      compare(userChoice);
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a little CSS, but that isn't the problem.

I put a place to see what is being called and it seems like the way choice is calling looked at in the compare function isn't working.

I need another set of eyes. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This is what I get in the browser:

Rock, Paper, Scissors Game
ROCK

PAPER

undefined

This game is a draw, you need to play another game.

Comment: `compare(userChoice);` -- you're passing in the function `userChoice` here rather than the user's choice, which I'm sure you didn't mean to do.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: I do need to put into the userChoice function because I need to valid the choice and choice is passed into userChoice.

Comment: I have used the inspect feature on the browser, but I haven't learned how to use a debugger yet.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in the `userChoice` function to `compare()` rather than the user's actual choice. Replace this bit:

```
//Declare variable result and set it's value by calling the compare function to display the result
compare(userChoice);
```

with this:

```
//Declare variable result and set it's value by calling the compare function to display the result
compare(document.getElementById("user").innerHTML);
```

Comment: But then the choice won't be validated and it won't make it uppercase so that the compare works.

Comment: When you call `userChoice(getChoice());` the user supplies his choice and it is saved in `<p id="user"></p>`. When you pass in the function `userChoice` you are NOT passing in the value of `<p id="user">ROCK</p>`, you're passing in the actual function code of `userChoice`. So when you say `choice + num` after passing in the function, you're really saying `function userChoice(choice) {
  choice = choice.toUpperCase();
  if (choice != "ROCK" && choice != "PAPER" && choice != "SCISSORS") {
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "You did not enter ROCK, PAPER, or SCISSORS, ... + num`

Comment: Take these functions for example: `function foo() {return prompt();}` and `function bar(arg) {console.log(arg+'foo');}`.What will be logged if you call this? `foo();bar(foo);` and type "ROCK" in the prompt? It will not be `ROCKfoo`, it will be `function foo() {console.log(prompt());}foo`.

Comment: Another way you could get this to work is to change the last bit of `userChoice` from `document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = choice;` to `return choice;`, and then change the line `compare(userChoice);` to `compare(userChoice(getChoice()));`.